# Concurrent transactions and @TransactionalEventListener order in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

If I have a method declared like this:

```
@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
public void afterTxCommit(MyObject myObject) {
    ....
}
```

Given that there are two concurrent transactions, `T1` and `T2`, and `T1` ends (slightly) before `T2`:

1. Will `afterTxCommit` be invoked synchronously for `T1` *before* it's invoked for `T2` with default Spring configuration?
2. If this is not the case, how can you configure Spring to make sure that `afterTxCommit` is guaranteed to be synchronously executed in the same order as transactions are committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. The listener will be invoked in the same thread as the transaction. So, if two transactions are executed concurrently, their listener will be invoked concurrently, too.
2. If the Spring bean where this listener method is defined is a singleton, then making it `synchronized` will make sure that the method will be executed by one thread at a time, but there is no guarantee on the order: the thread scheduler  might choose to invoke the listener of the second transaction before the listener of the first one, even though the first one committed first. I'm pretty sure there is no way to do what you want by just configuring Spring.

That sounds like a design smell to me: if two concurrent transactions are concurrent, then they should be independant, and the order shouldn't matter. But it's hard to advise anything concrete without knowing what you're trying to achieve.